# Renaming thousand files with similar names

Tags: bash, shell, files, rename

I'm creating a bash script to rename my files. The files are in the same folder and all look something like this

1xxx_(bunch of characters)=(bunch of characters)=1234567890

Now what i want is to leave just the last 1234567890.
Basically deleting every character from the front to the second occurrence of =

Comment: Are you familiar with the `${var##pattern}` [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) construct?

Comment: I'm sad to say,but no,i'm not familiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell's parameter expansion feature: in particular

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
       Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
       a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
       the  beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the
       expansion is the expanded value of parameter with  the  shortest
       matching  pattern  (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pat‐
       tern (the ``##'' case) deleted.
```

So something like

```
for file in *; do echo mv -- "$file" "${file##*=}"; done
```

(remove the `echo` if it appears to do the right thing).

---

One issue you may face is that filenames may become non-unique once the prefixes are removed. You can either choose to skip renaming these cases using the `-n` or `--no-clobber` option to `mv`:

```
for file in *; do mv --no-clobber -- "$file" "${file##*=}"; done
```

or use the `-b` or `--backup` option to create distinct backups: most straightforwardly

```
for file in *; do mv --backup=numbered -- "$file" "${file##*=}"; done
```

which will add distinguishing suffixes `.~1~`, `.~2~` and so on.

Comment: As you stated it works great,but now i figured out i have couple of hundreds files with the same characters,like 1393514394 so the second occurrence is not renamed,any way to add "a" like 1393514394a ,1393514394 b etc for the duplicate files ?

Comment: @OneStyle07 look at the `-b` or `--backup` options of the `mv` command: for example, adding `--backup=numbered` will add default suffixes like `.~1~`, `.~2~`

Comment: What that `--` is doing in the `mv` command of your answer?

Comment: @Kira the `--` is a (more-or-less) standard way to denote the end of command options: it just makes commands like this safe in the case that there are filenames beginning with a hyphen (in this case there wouldn't be, given the `1xxx*` glob).

Comment: @OneStyle07 please see edits

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you,it worked great :) Thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The perl rename script (comes standard in debian/ubuntu, or available here: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt ) will rename files based on a regular expression. with `-n` it will just print the named files without actually renaming them, allowing you to test before performing the action:

```
# Check before renaming...
$ rename -n 's/^.*=//' *
1xxx_DSAFDSAFDSFA=FDAFDSAFDSAFSDA=12341243142 renamed as 12341243142

# now rename all files
$ rename 's/^.*=//' *
```

It is very flexible tool, as it can easily operate on files based on wildcards (e.g. `*` for all files or `*.txt` for all text files), and it accepts any perl regular expression.

Comment: It is `sed` for file name: sed does file content, rename does their names.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can save the day here too. I'm using `cp` there, change it to `mv` if you like:

```
ls | awk -F"=" '{system("cp -i "$0" "$3)}'
```

I would use `-i` as a `cp` parameter too, just to be safe.

Comment: I get                   sh: 1402190714: command not found
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: Did you try to add parameters to `mv`? Make use to put it inside the quotes and to put spaces around it. I've edited the answer to show that.